# Access web.config settings using WCF Impersonation with net.tcp binding

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, impersonation

I'm trying to use impersonation with my WCF service (using net.tcp binding) hosted in IIS 7. I've got to the point where it's impersonating the client but whenever I try to access any configuration settings in the web.config using Settings.Default.SomeSetting it throws a SettingsPropertyNotFoundException.
Is this because IIS is running under a different identity to the impersonated identity? If so what settings must I change to allow them to run under the same impersonated identity?
I've tried setting the "servicePrincipalName" property without any success.

I've included my web.config settings below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TestServices">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpbinding"
          contract="Test.ITestService">
          <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mextcp" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>        
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>          
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpbinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" portSharingEnabled="true">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I wasn't properly impersonating my client on the server side as I needed to set the allowedImpersonationLevel on my client to "Impersonation". This defaults to "Identification". So when I tested using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name I got the correct user name but the user wasn't actually impersonated.

So adding this to my client web.config did the trick:

```
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/Test/Service/TestService.svc"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ITestService"
          contract="ServiceReference.ITestService" name="NetTcpBinding_ITestService"
          behaviorConfiguration="ImpersonationBehavior">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ImpersonationBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```